# Android AlertDialog BUTTON_POSITIVE / BUTTON_NEGATIVE order

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I know that pre-ICS, the standard order in an AlertDialog is "Ok" / "Cancel" and that has changed in ICS (the standard order became "Cancel" / "Ok")

However, even if I use

```
alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", ...)
alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", ...)
```

I get the same result running the application in pre-ICS and in ICS: in both the positive option appears at left, negative at right.

Shouldn't this be automatic, since we are using System constants to define where positive (AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE) and negative (AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) are?

**EDIT:**
After accepting the solution, I would like to refer that I am now using the following code to set the buttons in the correct order in ICS and pre-ICS:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) { // pre-ICS, show Positive/Negative
    alertDialog.setButton(labelPositive, positiveListener);
    alertDialog.setButton2(labelNegative, negativeListener);    
} else { // ICS+, show Negative/Positive
    alertDialog.setButton(labelNegative, negativeListener);
    alertDialog.setButton2(labelPositive, positiveListener);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expect as an answer... The constant values are the same, Android simply switched the wording.

You probably know that `BUTTON_POSITIVE` has no mandate that it link to an "affirmative" action. So `BUTTON_POSITIVE` can have the "Cancel" code as readily as the "Ok" code, in fact they are just constants (positive: -1, neutral: -2, negative: -3).

Imagine a pre-ICS Dialog with the positive (left) and negative (right) buttons respectively labeled `<-` and `->`. Watch what happens if ICS *did* automatically switch the values of the existing constants:

```
        Pre-ICS Dialog          |        Post-ICS Dialog
--------------------------------|-------------------------------
      | <- |       | -> |       |      | -> |       | <- |
 ie.   "Ok"       "Cancel"      |     "Cancel"       "Ok"
```

The buttons no longer make sense...

In short, ICS would've broken existing code in one generation by *automatically reordering* the buttons. So if the idea that the order of the default labels is *not* consistent in pre- and post-ICS devices **truly** bothers you, then consider using their constant values (`-1`, `-2`, `-3`) rather than their aliases.

Comment: So in order to have the buttons to appear "automatically" as in system (pre-ICS: OK/Cancel, ICS+: Cancel/OK), probably the best way is to use `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) { //pre-ICS, show Positive/Negative } else { //ICS+, show Negative/Positive }` right?

Comment: Yes, that is the easiest way.